# Loading file links from database with PHP

Tags: php, sql

As a beginner I need some information. I've been trying to piece together bits for an online user uploading and sharing site like newgrounds.com

I don't have any code so far, just questions.

My big one at the moment, is how can I display SQL entries as file links? The idea is when a user uploads a file, an entry is created with the username, file name and file location. The file location will be a folder relevant to the user's username. But how will I create a link to that file onto a most recent uploads page?

Comment: You can have a directory like `/path/to/site/uploads/user/file.ext`, and then a SQL table that has `user_id|file_name`.  Then loop through the rows for `user_id=X` and echo links like `http://website.com/uploads/user/file.ext`.

Comment: That seems brilliant, thanks. Do you think you could give me a small example of how to implement this onto the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to perform an SQL query everytime you list all the files anyway, so when you do your query, make sure to include the `file location` field and parse it in your PHP.

For example, if you are using MySQL, you can do `SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE 'user_id' = $userid ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 10` and loop through those to display all the fields in your PHP code.

Comment: That's very useful, thank you. Do you think you could show me roughly what the PHP script would look like? I understand accessing the table, just don't how I'd put what you just said into the script :)

Comment: Please see [PHP - MySQLi Result Fetch Assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).